# Authentication Error with Homestead after Restoring from Backup

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead, ssh-keys

I accidentally ran `vagrant destroy` before forgetting to backup my database. I replaced my VM directory with a backup and then corrected the UUID so they matched.  However, when trying to start Homestead, I get an authentication error:

```
$ homestead up
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/pre-rubygems.rb:31: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:78: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: There was a problem while downloading the metadata for your box
==> default: to check for updates. This is not an error, since it is usually due
==> default: to temporary network problems. This is just a warning. The problem
==> default: encountered was:
==> default: 
==> default: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
==> default: 
==> default: If you want to check for box updates, verify your network connection
==> default: is valid and try again.
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
default: Adapter 1: nat
default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
default: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

I can start Homestead in the VirtualBox GUI and login with vagrant/vagrant but this does not help to get my sites online as `No Input File Specified` is displayed when attempting to access the sites in a browser.
The ssh keys were previously setup on this machine (backup is only a few days old) so I assumed the authentication would still work.
How do I get Homestead back up? Using OSX Sierra, VirtualBox 5.0.14, Homestead 2.2.1, Vagrant 1.8.1

I am a bit lost when it comes to ssh keys, but I've pulled up the following:
In OSX terminal:

```
$ vagrant ssh-config
Host default
HostName 127.0.0.1
User vagrant
Port 2200
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
StrictHostKeyChecking no
PasswordAuthentication no
IdentityFile "/Users/Myself/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"
IdentitiesOnly yes
LogLevel FATAL

$ cat /Users/Myself/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY------
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEA6NF8iallvQVp22WDk..... omitted ...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Then I can ssh into the Homestead instance and run:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADA .... omitted ...6KI3AcGkjQOt/ vagrant
```

Back on Terminal in OSX, I have:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,FD8746C7776F06E98C74CBABEE95360C

MffswxNSLA1bn9/APO9/mb5QdF1...omitted
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Do some of these keys need to be the same?

EDIT: Successful mysqldump on the Homestead machine! But -- I can't figure out how to move it to my local machine.  The shared folders don't seem to be working.  I can see the home/vagrant/Code directory but it is empty and does not appear to be liked with my local version. Within Settings > Shared Folders I see
Folder Path: /Users/Myself/Code
Folder Name: home_vagrant_Code
But that does no seem to be pulling up any files from /Users/Myself/Code.
If I can just get the mysqldump off the VM, I'll rollback the VM back to when it was working and reinstate the DB from there.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to restore the backup VM due to the ssh authentication errors.
However, I was able to ssh into the machine and perform a mysqldump.
To access the file, I ran into issues with mounting the virtual CD, it never worked.  Thankfully I ran:
`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils`
Then I was able to add a shared directory.
Finding this directory was also not obvious as it was located in the media director with an "sf" prefix (shared folder).  So once I set up the folder through the VirtualBox GUI I had to run:
`ls /media`
And thankfully the directory was there.
I then copied the sql dump file to this directory and was able to see it on my local machine.

The next step was to revert back to the old VM folder with TimeMachine (still unclear why the backup did not work) and then ran `homestead up` and everything ran smoothly from there as I was able to access phpmyadmin and import the mysqldump file.